# how to get ajax response first part

Tags: javascript, ajax

I used ajax to call an URL with dataType HTML. It returns response having two part like accesstoken=1&expires=452. I want only accesstoken..I use alert(response), but it returns both. How to get accesstoken? My function is:

```
  $.ajax({
  type:"POST",
  url:theUrl,
  dataType:"html",
  success:function(res){
  alert(res);
  }
  });
```

Comment: can u plz add more info? exact url or response u r getting?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the split function like this.

```js
var test = "accesstoken=1&expires=452.";
var array = test.split("&");
alert(array[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use split function

Ex-

```
 $.ajax({
     type:"POST",
     url:theUrl,
     dataType:"html",
     success:function(res){
         alert(res);
         var result=res.split('&');
         var access_token=result[0].split('=');
         var access_token_val=access_token[1];
      }
 });
```